# Windows 8 Open Folder With

Tags: windows

I decided to switch to a different file explorer. Like how Windows uses Windows Explorer. I will be using MultiCommander. I would like any folders that are opened, to be opened in MultiCommander. How do I do this? Folders could be anything on the desktop, start menu etc. You could also open the folder in other programs such as WinRAR or 7z.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://forum.multicommander.com/forum/index.php/topic,936.msg2823.html#msg2823) hack should work for you.

> Edit the PATH below or inside the attached .reg file to match the path to where you have MultiCommander.exe

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell]
@="MultiCommander"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\MultiCommander]
@="Open in MultiCommander"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\MultiCommander\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MultiCommander\\MultiCommander.exe\" /OPEN %1"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell]
@="MultiCommander"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MultiCommander]
@="Open in MultiCommander"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\MultiCommander\command]
@="\"C:\\Program Files\\MultiCommander\\MultiCommander.exe\" /OPEN %1"
```

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. One problem, I now have two things added to the right click menu. As you can see here: http://screencast.com/t/2PNNfeeOSsfp How can I delete those?

Comment: Oops, never mind, that came from me derping around with the registry before I asked this question!

Comment: @ChristopherSmith okay, I'm glad it worked for you. =)